# Storing the value of cookie in variable but doesn't appear in cookie data in request body in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

There are lots of cookies present and I need to extract those cookie and pass them as a post parameter in further request. So i have changed the setting for them in jmeter.property file as
save.cookies=true 
check.cookies=false

Then after running the test, I got those cookie value in debug sampler as ${COOKIE_}

**EXPECTED:**
GET data:

Cookie Data:
private_content_version=e17f5f6a5ed9557378a6f85fa2202c0e;form_key=mCPI56sUAl6bqAJdqq;

**Actual Result**
GET data:

[no cookies]

I have passed in the value in HTTP header manager as 
name=private_content_version
Value=${COOKIE_private_content_version}

name=form_key
Value=${COOKIE_Form_key}

But instead of value, same variable is passed as ${COOKIE_private_content_version}
Also there are multiple cookies and I need to fetch them too and pass them in further http request payload,but unable to do that.What I AM MISSING?Please help

DO I NEED TO ADD THEM COOKIE MANAGER UNDER EACH OF THE HTTP REQUEST?OR DEFINED IN GLOBALLY?
Also how to define them  ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually add cookies in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), the Cookie Manager should normally handle them.

If for some reason you need to build [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header manually make sure to use strict **Cookie** name and in the value one or more name/value pairs of cookies separated by semicolons

[image]

You might find [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) article useful, it contains comprehensive information on HTTP Cookie Manager configuration and troubleshooting.